# Error trying to bundle install a ruby new generated project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems, bundler

I just started in Ruby, so after a lookup on internet I installed it using rvm. The version of ruby is 2.6.3. This is the output for `ruby -v`:

```
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
```

I also installed Rails using `gem install rails` and get the version 6.0.2.1.
After that I created a project called blog using `rails new blog`, the project was created and in the directory I run `bundle install` and get the following error message:

```
There was an error while trying to write to
`/home/ramon/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions`.                                             
It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
```

After that I run `sudo bundle install` and get this error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.3
```

But my Ruby version is already 2.6.3. 
After searching for answers on internet I tried these solutions:
`sudo gem update bundler`
`sudo gem install bundler`
`sudo gem install rails`

But all of this returned the same error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory
```

Then I run `which ruby` and got this: `/home/ramon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby`

and added this line do .bashrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ramon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby
```

But still got the error.

I tried changing this line in /etc/login.defs to:

```
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/$
```

And /etc/environment to:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/$
```

But I dont know what to do anymore, tried every solution on internet and nothing works.

One thing I tried was running `which ruby` as superuser, and I got nothing.
Maybe it is a PATH problem or a permission problem. But I dont know anymore what to do.

I use lubuntu 19.04.

Comment: try putting this line at the end of your bashrc/zshrc(shell rc) file `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"` and reopen a new window of the terminal and run `rvm list` to see the list of all rubies installed from rvm, if there is any, do: `rvm use ruby-version-from-list>`

Comment: What's the version of ruby in the rails project's gemfile? If you want to use 2.6.3 then change the 2.7 in the Gemfile to 2.6.3.

Comment: just use a [rvm](https://rvm.io) to manage your ruby versions.

Comment: Hey guy, sorry about the delay, different timezones. Just tried the Surya solution, but doesn't work, I got the same error, and the gemfile is specifying 2.6.3.
this is what i got when i run rvm list:
   ruby-2.5.5 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.6.3 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.7.0 [ x86_64 ]
# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

Comment: My ruby version is correct, 2.6.3.

Comment: Never install gems with sudo. Thats a surefire way to get permission issues and using sudo is inherently dangerous - especially when installing gems since they can execute code at install time. Run `sudo gem uninstall bundler` and then reinstall  bundler with `gem install bundler`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two versions of Ruby , so you may try this:

```
rvm --default use [correct version number]
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work at all. It was already there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file **.ruby-version** in the main folder of project and put ruby version inside:

**2.6.3**

or

**2.7.0**

because I don't know which Ruby version you want do use.

Save and go to the console and do this:

1. cd ..
2. cd blog (your project name)

Comment: Nope, that was already there.